# Tag synonym request: [flutter-null-safety] does not actually exist and should not be a tag

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

The [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) language recently introduced a new feature called "Null Safety". There is a tag for it: [dart-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-null-safety).

As of today it has roughly 360 questions tagged with it, it has a wiki, it seems to be what we want.

And then there is [flutter-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-null-safety). Flutter is a framework, maybe *the* framework people use with Dart to create apps. But there is no such thing as Flutter null-safety. Yes, Flutter uses Dart and Dart has null safety. The tag has no wiki and roughly 30 questions tagged with it, sometimes questions are tagged with both.

I would suggest removing the [flutter-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-null-safety) tag by editing the questions and exchanging it with [dart-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-null-safety), because it's just a typo by someone that didn't know better. In fact, I will start doing so. But since we are the site for people that didn't know better to come to and get to know better, I'm afraid this tag will pop up again sooner or later.

Can we please have a synonym that makes the **misunderstood** [flutter-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-null-safety) a synonym of the **correct** [dart-null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart-null-safety)?