Why does [dart-null-safety] just link to [dart]?
The tag dart-null-safety just links to dart. Not sure why, I guess it was made a synonym/duplicate.
Why is that? It is a pretty specific subset of Dart, with specific questions and specific answers. One can be an expert for this subset of questions. That is why this tag was created.
I could see a strong argument for using a combination of the dart tag combined with the null-safety tag. Given that the tag guidelines say it should be used together with dart, making dart-null-safety a synonym of the more generic null-safety would make sense.
But a synonym for dart? Why is that? I type in good information, like dart dart-null-safety and poof one of them is gone. Makes no sense.
Who did this, and why?

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412065/tag-synonym-request-flutter-null-safety-does-not-actually-exist-and-should-no

Has there been some cleanup operation by people not knowledgeable in the actual tags? I checked my posts and there have been some trivially wrong tags applied. Like "flutter-future". Such a thing does not exist, flutter is a framework, it has no future class of it's own, it uses Dart. "flutter-future" is like saying "spring-string" in Java. That's nonsense, it's a java string, the spring framework just uses it. Something weird is going on here.

You can find synonyms here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms  (sorry for not being able to deep link to "dart", you have to search for it by yourself) and there you can find who suggested the synonym and when it was applied.

@rene Is there a way to appeal or revert those changes?

@nvoigt [[tag:synonym-removal-request]]. I'm with you, there - sounds like these shouldn't have been synonymised.
